# Quantum Mechanics in electric field derived from QED

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, hamiltonian

How can one find a sector of QFT that behaves like (relativistic) quantum mechanics?
To be precise, we are interested in obtaining the (relativistic) Hamiltonian of a charged QM particle
\begin{equation}
H \psi(x) = \sqrt{\tilde p^2 + m^2} \psi(x) + q A_o(x) \psi(x)
\end{equation}
where $A_o$ is the scalar potential of a (static) electric field and $\tilde p_a = p_a - q A_a$.

In a realistic setting, this is probably best compared to the 1-particle excitation of some matter field coupling to an electromagnetic field which generates the potential.

1. Does it make more sense to consider standard QED (fermionic spin-1/2 matter coupled to $U(1)$ gauge theory) or scalar QED (spin-0 matter field coupled to $U(1)$ gauge theory)? Should both have QM as a limit?
2. For scalar QED we would start with the Lagrangian
   \begin{equation}
   \mathcal{L} = (D_\mu\phi)^* D^\mu \phi -m^2 \phi^2
   \end{equation}
   with $\phi$ being the complex scalar field, $D_\mu =\partial_\mu - i q A_\mu$ and assuming $A_\mu$ to be fixed. I think upon Legendre transformation we get momentum $\pi:=(\partial_0-iqA_0)\phi^*$ and that the Hamiltonian operator becomes something like
   \begin{align}
    H &= \int d^3x (|\pi|^2+(D_a\phi)^* D^a\phi + m^2|\phi|^2+iqA_o (\pi^*\phi-\pi\phi^*)) \\
   &=\int dp^3 (\omega_p (a_pa_p^\dagger + b_p b_p^\dagger) + iqA_o j_p)
   \end{align}
   with covariance $\omega_p=\sqrt{p^2+m^2+q^2A_aA^a}$ and in terms of particle/antiparticle ladder operators.  But while $\omega_p$ features the correct $p^2+m^2$ contribution for the charged QM particle (first equation), why is the part involving $A$ different?
3. For fermions and Lagrangian $\mathcal L = \phi^* (i\gamma^\mu D_\mu -m)\phi$, I struggle to express it in a form where the Hamiltonian looks somewhat close to the one before (covariance and ladder operators).